# Get the common name of items in array and save the rest of the each one

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of items, where is ID, name, etc... And I want to get their common name and also get the rest of the name of each item. I made a script, that gets this common name. This one is probably not the best for the performance, but it works. Here is the code:

```
$items = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Knife red big'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Knife blue big'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'name' => 'Knife green small'
    ),
);
$commonWords = array();

foreach($items as $key => $item) {
    $testWords = explode(' ', $item['name']);

    if(empty($commonWords)) {
        $commonWords = $testWords;
    } else {
        $newCommonWords = array();

        foreach($commonWords as $word) {
            if(in_array($word, $testWords)) {
                $newCommonWords[] = $word;
            }
        }

        $commonWords = $newCommonWords;
        $newItemName = str_replace(implode(' ', $commonWords), '', $item['name']);
        $items[$key]['altName'] = $newItemName;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r(array(
    'items' => $items,
    'commonName' => implode(' ', $commonWords)
));
echo "</pre>";
```

This is what I get:

```
Array
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Knife red big
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => Knife blue big
                    [altName] => Knife blue big
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => Knife green small
                    [altName] =>  green small
                )

        )

    [commonName] => Knife
)
```

My goal is that each item in the array will have new parameter `altName`, where will be the rest of its name, in this example everything except `Knife`. How can I achieve such a thing, even for the first one?

Comment: Please provide the desired output array

Comment: My expected output is the same like I posted, for example that `Knife green small` did all right, but I want all of them to have same output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to use [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to build the common words array, and [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to build the alt names :

```
$items = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Knife red big'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Knife blue big'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'name' => 'Knife green small'
    ),
);
$commonWords = array();

foreach ($items as $k=>$item) {
    if ($k == 0)
        $commonWords = explode(' ', $item['name']);
    else
        $commonWords = array_intersect($commonWords, explode(' ', $item['name']));
}

foreach ($items as $k=>$item) {
    $name_array = explode(' ', $item['name']);
    $altName_array = array_diff($name_array, $commonWords);
    $items[$k]['altName'] = implode(' ', $altName_array);
}

var_dump($commonWords);
var_dump($items);
```

Result :

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'Knife' (length=5)

array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 1
      'name' => string 'Knife red big' (length=13)
      'altName' => string 'red big' (length=7)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 2
      'name' => string 'Knife blue big' (length=14)
      'altName' => string 'blue big' (length=8)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 3
      'name' => string 'Knife green small' (length=17)
      'altName' => string 'green small' (length=11)
```

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot! Also adding `$items[$k]['altName'] = ucfirst(implode(' ', $altName_array));` makes it much more beautiful.

Comment: Sure, but then I'd recommend you replace `explode(' ', $item['name'])` by `explode(' ', strtolower($item['name']))` everywhere so that every word is extracted/compared/stored in lower case. Then `ucfirst` would capitalize every first letter of each word for the display.

Comment: Ooh, I found a bug in it. When you change their names and put something common after something unique, it will print wrong output. For example, I change names to `Knife red plus big`, `Knife blue plus big` and `Knife green plus small` and result was `Knife plus` so that one is wrong. It should find common words only up to first unique. What should I do?

Comment: Well, both `Knife` and `plus` are common elements to all three entries, so it's a perfectly normal result. I'll see if I can adapt the code to find common elements only up to the first unique word.

Comment: I applied my part of code `$newCommonWords = array();

        foreach($name_array as $key => $val) {
            if(in_array($val, $commonWords)) {
                $newCommonWords[] = $val;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        $commonWords = $newCommonWords;` instead of `array_intersect` and seems to be working.